# css селектор. protractor. можно ли добавить переменные внутрь css селектора?

Tags: css-selectors

задача - прокликать по периметру сетки. если использую css селектор с цифрами

```
(element(by.css(".mainGrid .row:nth-child(2) .icon:nth-child(3)")).click() )
```

, то работает, но когда пытаюсь сделать через цикл

```
".row:nth-child(i+1) .icon:nth-child(j+1)"
```

, ругается на селектор *(An invalid or illegal selector was specified)*.

Я подозреваю что не нравятся переменные, но как их туда правильно поместить?

Comment: приветите ваш код

Comment: @Zhihar, код уже был приведен, просто не выделен

Comment: извините за кривую верстку, это мой первый пост ))